# second inner join overwrites first one

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need some help with SQL Joins in laravel query builder for a project. So I have these Tables.

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixY6u.png)

I want to join them thusly so that in the end I have something like this.

```
Name date baker
Ddd.   12.12.2021 smith
Bbb.    02.02.2022 Randy
```

So what I did was

```
$oders = DB::table(‘orders’)
        ->select('client_name’ , ’cake_orders.date’ , ’cake_orders.baker’, ’muffin_orders.date’, ’muffin_orders.baker’) 
        
->leftjoin(‘cake_orders’, ‘orders.order_id, '=', ‘cake_orders.id’)
        
->leftjoin(‘muffin’_orders, ‘orders.order_id’, '=', ‘muffiin_orders.id’) 
        ->get();
```

What I get though is something like this.

```
Name date             baker 
Bbb.   02.02.2022 Randy
```

So for some reason I am missing the first join. I am an sql novice and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to list all cakes and muffins at the same table list.
for this, you should union. at this sql, your table has null for one join, so second one overwrite other join. because they have same field name.

union : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#unions